# Infopath form values submit to PDF

Tags: forms, pdf, infopath

I'm trying to use values selected out of my InfoPath form to be displayed in a nicely manner on a PDF..For example a user selects a contact that is pulled from a database..and then that contacts information is displayed in a pdf once they hit submit on the infopath form..any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my codeplex project [IP2HTML](http://ip2html.codeplex.com/). It allows you to convert an InfoPath form/view to HTML (you can do the HTML to PDF conversion with any 3rd party tool you like). Click [here](http://ip2html.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Usage) to see how it's used within a IP 2010 form.

In your case, i would create a custom view that displays only the selected contact, and when the user clicks submit the pdf is generated. This, however, requires code within your form.